# Implementing a Tree data structure based on the DOM in PHP. How do NodeLists work?

Tags: php, dom, tree, implementation, nodes

I am currently trying to implement a Tree-like data structure in PHP loosely based on the DOM. So far I have defined two interfaces, Node and NodeList. Here are some simplified versions:

```
interface Node {

    public function hasChildNodes();

    public function childNodes();

    public function parentNode();

    public function hasParentNode();

    public function nodeValue();

    public function appendChild($name, Node $node);

    public function removeChild($name);
}
```

and

```
interface NodeList {

    public function size();

    public function item(); 
}
```

Here is a quick example of how it could work:

```
$node = new Node($someValue);
$node->appendChild(new Node($anotherValue));
$nodelist = $node->childNodes();
```

However, There is one problem. The reason why I wanted to base the interface on PHP's DOM interface is because I wanted to ensure that NodeLists have a reduced interface which keeps the tree structure from being altered without the knowledge of the Nodes themselves. All child appending or removing is therefore performed on the Node, ensuring that the structure of the data stored does not become erroneous by manipulating NodeLists.

So when Node::childNodes() is called, how should it create a NodeList in it's implementation? I searched through the PHP documentation to find out.

There is no public interface for appending/removing nodes from DOMNodeList. So how does DOMNode append/remove child nodes to its own childNodes property? DOMNode couldn't have access to protected properties/methods unless it extended DOMNodeList. If DOMNode actually holds an array of child nodes that DOMNodeList simply references, then how does DOMNodeList have access to it? There is no method that adds a reference to the parent DOMNode. Even if this reference was present, there is no way to access said array of child nodes through DOMNode's interface.

So I guess the question could be summed up with the following:

**How do NodeLists and Nodes access each other's internal storage/references when there appears to be no interface to do so?**

I hope I have just missed something obvious because it seems like this should be easy to figure out. If anyone could just point me towards somewhere I could see a working implementation, that would also suffice as an answer.

Comment: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/dom/DynamicNodeList.cpp?rev=41093#L31

Comment: @Esailija this is C/C++ code? I'm not very good with reading C/C++, I only know Java and PHP. Am I correct in thinking that NodeLists are linked lists? So that a Node needs a reference to first/last and siblings? +1 for hasty reply, thanks.

Comment: A node has references to parent, nextSibling, previousSibling, lastChild and firstChild. NodeList has reference to the root node of the dom subtree that the list represents. To locate list item N, you would access firstChild of the root node of the list, and loop to the Nth sibling via nextSibling references. So the lists themselves don't have references other than root node. If you don't use caching, then you always have to do this traversing for any kind of access and the list appears automatically live.

Comment: Note that nodes don't have childNodes reference, it just returns a new live nodelist when accessed with root node set to the node of which .childNodes you accessed.

Comment: @Esailija Yes that's what I thought, thanks for clearing that up. Given this lengthy traversal that involves looping to the Nth sibling I thought a NodeMap would be superior. I already have a Map class which is an array wrapper that enforces key-value structure. Perhaps Node could be given a property of type Map that stores child nodes. This could be wrapped by a NodeMap and passed at construction. The wrapping would restrict access and the map would be an object so would I be correct in thinking it would still be "live" because the Map would be passed by reference?

Comment: @Esailija Ah I see, the php doc suggests that it stores a reference to a DOMNodeList object as a property as opposed to instatiating one upon request. But I suppose it makes little difference seeing as the time of instantiation shouldn't affect it's correctness if it's live.

Comment: @Esailija if you copy what you explained about NodeLists as an answer I will accept it.